# Salesforce API: Is there a way to determine the relationship between two random tables

Tags: salesforce

Given two Salesforce table names, I want to be to determine if there is a parent/child relationship between them and if the relationship exists which table is the parent.

I have this method that works with simple cases, but it is not optimized since I have to go through all the child relationships of both tables in the worst case. I am also not confident that this approach handles all cases.

```
private String getParent(String table1, String table2) throws Exception
{
    DescribeSObjectResult[] describeSObjectResults =
        pc.describeSObjects(new String[] {table1, table2});

    // Child relationships of table1
    for (ChildRelationship cr : describeSObjectResults[0].getChildRelationships())
    {
        // table1 has a child matching table2 
        if (table2.equalsIgnoreCase(cr.getChildSObject()))
        {
            return table1;
        }
    }
    // Child relationships of table2
    for (ChildRelationship cr : describeSObjectResults[1].getChildRelationships())
    {
        // table1 has a child matching table2 
        if (table1.equalsIgnoreCase(cr.getChildSObject()))
        {
            return table2;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("There is no parent/child relationship.");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd change anything here. It's simple, clear to understand & maintain code.

You could make-do with describing only 1 object - going "down" to child relationships, going "up" by examining all fields and checking if [fieldDescribe](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) methods like `getReferenceTo()` return something meaningful.

But I wouldn't do that:

1. It means you have to describe every single field - and only few of them will be actually lookups.
2. It means extra headache when the lookup is "mutant":

   - `Case.OwnerId` can point to `User` or `Queue`
   - `Event.WhoId` can point to any object that has "allow Activities" ticked
   - `Report.ParentId` can point to `Folder`, `User` or `Organization`

If you're worried about performance... This is something external, right? Not Apex but Java or maybe C# (this `throws Exception` bit).

You could try prepopulating some helper table in your DB and then referencing this cached data.

You could try having a cached copy of "Enterprise WSDL" for your org and I'm sure it'll be faster to scan locally kept XML than go & ask SF every time (you'd need to remember fetching a fresh copy every once in a while). You could even combine it to have "local DB as cache generated from WSDL plus if nothing found - then make the expensive describe calls"...